# Creating new discussion using designer 2010 workflow not showing discussion item correctly

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, office-365

I have created a designer 2010 workflow in SPD 2013 which will create a discussion in discussion board when a user will add an item to my custom list. Now item is created but when I checked its root folder is not showing correct. please see below images.

[image]

now when I go to my newly created discussion it is showing as below.

[image]

I have checked its URL and in it I found that root folder is written as `"{ID}_.000"`

```
{Discussion Board URL}/Flat.aspx?RootFolder={Discussion Board Server Relative URL}/**42_.000**&FolderCTID=0x0120020039F6B139DF760B4CBB50CA61AF90EE33
```

and if I create discussion manually its URL is showing as below.

```
{Discussion Board URL}/Flat.aspx?RootFolder={Discussion Board Server Relative URL}/**test**&FolderCTID=0x0120020039F6B139DF760B4CBB50CA61AF90EE33
```

As you can see that root folder value is different. I think this issue is coming because of that only.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I've been having the same issue with no luck.